# angular select ng-change event don`t fire if we chose selected value

Tags: angularjs, events

Is there another event to get value of select even if we chose already selected value

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.sizes = [ {code: 1, name: 'n1'}, {code: 2, name: 'n2'}];
$scope.update = function() {
console.log('updated')
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gh7b30kj/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
     <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

 <select  name="abc"  ng-model="item" ng-change="update(item)" >
              <option value="">Select</option>
              <option name="age" ng-value="{{size.code}}" ng-repeat="size in sizes"
                 value="{{size.code}}" >
                 {{size.name  }}
              </option>
           </select>


{{item.code}} {{item.name}}
</div>
```

controller

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.sizes = [ {code: 1, name: 'n1'}, {code: 2, name: 'n2'}];
 $scope.update = function(item) {
 alert(item)
}
}
```

Comment: Nope. If I chose n1 and then chose n1 again alert don`t show :((

Comment: Change event fire only when dropdown value change . if you select same value then change event will no fire

Comment: So and what event I need to use?

Comment: if you want a event for every click does't matter value is changed or not use ng-click="event()" but it is not a good practise

Comment: I hope you got your solution if yes then accept answer

Comment: No. I don`t found nice solution yet

Comment: select ng-change event never fire if you choose selected value.your question are not correct.

Comment: And what event I need to use?